# FaultException not thrown at WCF client. Instead I am getting Communication Exception

Tags: c#, wcf, faultexception

I have an simple WCF server where I am throwing `FaultException<InvalidOperationException>` but on client side i only get the Communication exception with error  below.

> The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error
>   processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the
>   remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket
>   timeout was '00:00:59.8080000'.

See below for code I am having, please help and let me know if something is missing.

Service

```
[OperationContract]
[FaultContract(typeof(InvalidOperationException))]
bool DoWork()
```

Service implementation code

```
public bool DoWork()
    {var invalidOperationException =
          new InvalidOperationException(
            "Can't dowork", exception);

        // throw InvalidOperationException as an FaultException to the service consumer.
        throw new FaultException<InvalidOperationException>(
          invalidOperationException,
             exception.Message,
              new FaultCode("Test Message"),
              "DoWork");
}
```

Client side code.

```
try
{
 var service = new ServiceClient();
 var result = service.DoWork();
}
catch (TimeoutException timeoutException)
          {

          }
          catch (FaultException<InvalidOperationException> invalidOperationException)
          {

          }
          catch (FaultException unknownFault)
          {

          }
          catch (CommunicationException communicationException)
          {

          }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the inner exception provided in

```
var invalidOperationException =
      new InvalidOperationException(
        "Can't dowork", exception);
```

If you remove that it will work.

My guess is that It has something to do with trying to serialize an CLR exception.

Comment: Thanks I already removed inner exception and it is working fine. I was about to respond and saw your answer exactly saying the same. Any way thank you so much for the response.